# mysql Select WHERE AND is working strangely

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been battling with this for a good 5 hrs now my login script is now returning nothing.
At first it was allowing people with wrong details to Login; I made a few changes and it started denying all users, even the ones with correct login details. I removed my password condition and it retrieved the user correctly. I also then again removed the username condition and replaced it with the password condition and it retrieved all users with the same password, but when I have both conditions it returns `null`, wrong or right credentials...

```
<?php
  include( '../config.php' );

  session_start();
  if( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));     
    $salt = "ghvhgcfchgvbhvgkhbh";
    echo $username.'<br>';
    try{
      $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
      $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username And password = :password LIMIT 1";

      $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
      $stmt->bindValue( "username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $password . $salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
      $stmt->execute();

      $valid = $stmt->fetch();
      echo '<br> it fetches'.$valid['username'];
      print_r($valid);
      $con = null;
      if( $valid ) {
        echo '<br> its valid';
        print_r($valid);
        $_SESSION['user'][0] = $valid['username'];
        if (isset( $_SESSION['errors'] )){unset($_SESSION['errors']);}
        //if(!empty($_SESSION['LogUrl'])){header("Location: ../{$_SESSION['LogUrl']}");}
        else{header("Location:   ../index.php"); }
      } else {
        $_SESSION['errors'] = 'AuthLogin';
        header("Location: AuthPage.php");
      }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "chian ".$e->getMessage();
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Oops SeEye went blind!!!';
  }
?>
```

Here is my registration script just incase there's a change to my password that happens which i'm oblivious too...

```
<?php
   include( '../config.php' );
   //Include The Database Connection File 

   if( (isset( $_POST['register'] )) && empty($_SESSION['user']))//If a username has been submitted 
    {
     $username = $_POST['usernam'];//Some clean up :)
     $password = $_POST['password'];//Some clean up :)
     $salt = "ghvhgcfchgvbhvgkhbh";

   try{
     $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
     $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='.$username.'";

     $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );

     $stmt->execute();

     $row  = $stmt-> fetch();
     $con = null;
     if( !$row) {
             try {
                $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
                $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, Date_Joined) 
                VALUES(:username, :password,   :Date_Joined)";

    $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindValue( "username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $password . $salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->bindValue( "Date_Joined", date("Y-m-d"), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $stmt->execute();
    $con = null;
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'][0] = $_POST['usernam'];
    if (isset( $_SESSION['errors'] )){unset($_SESSION['errors']);}
      if(!empty($_SESSION['LogUrl'])){header("Location: {$_SESSION['LogUrl']}");}
       else{header("Location: ../index.php"); }
   }catch( PDOException $e ) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
   }
    else
       {
         echo '0ops something went wrong';//No Record Found - Username is available 
       }
  }catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
 } else {
     echo 'Oops SeEye went blind!!!';
   }
 ?>
```

Thank You in advance again

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem, but: If you are using parameterization to bind $password to the query, then you don't need to escape it first. And in fact you shouldn't, because you might end up double escaping some characters.

Comment: The obvious question: you're **sure** that there's a user with both the username and password that's failing?

Comment: Print username and password on screen when you want to log user in and then check it with the ones in database. BTW, you don't need to put `LIMIT 1` if usernames are unique which they should be.

Comment: Yes I created 4 different users with different username and 2 have the same passwords even wrote them down on a pad just to be sure

Comment: Chris I removed the escape thanks but since i had them on my register script will it cause a problem? MahanGM Strange but when I look at my hash password stored in my db and hash in my php scripts the passwords do not match

Comment: Why __are you using__ `mysql_real_escape_string` with PDO?

Comment: I've removed it hjpotter92

Comment: Could the fact that my password column data type is varbinary be of some cause or effect? coz the password are completely different as if they change some where during my registration I'll add my upload script just incase

Comment: Guys I'm sorry to have wasted ur time to those who have tried to help, it turns out after going through my cluttered and badly coded registration form that password input name was missing one 's'.. Thank u again